# How to parse this code using Jsoup with java?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

```
  <tr>
    <td align="left" colspan="8" width="100%"><p><em><b>value1</b></em></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <TR bgcolor="#ecffff">``
    <td align="center">value2</td>
    <td>value3</td>
  </tr>
```

need to get values 1-3 to diffrent String  variables

Comment: [jsoup.org](http://www.jsoup.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the following ressources:

1. [Jsoup Cookbook > Input](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/)
   *You'll learn how to parse any code using Jsoup with java.*
2. [Jsoup Cookbook > Extracting data > Use selector-syntax to find elements](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
   *You'll learn how to get (extract) values from any code.*
3. [try.jsoup.org](http://try.jsoup.org)
   *This is a sandbox where you can test any selector-syntax against any code.*

**See also:**

- [Jsoup Selector Syntax Complete Reference](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)